# JS: Object Properties Change in Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, ecmascript-6

I have this code:

```
class Obj {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "foo";
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Obj.prototype,'foo',{enumerable:false,writable:true});
Object.defineProperty(Obj,'foo',{enumerable:false,writable:true});

let obj = new Obj();

console.log(obj);
```

And my output is:

```
Obj { foo: 'foo' }
```

The problem is, I defined the enumerable property as false for foo. But when in the construct I use 'this.foo' that property change it.

I know I can put in the constructor:

```
Object.defineProperty(this,'foo',{enumerable:false,writable:true});
```

And my new output throws correctly:

```
Obj {}
```

But, my question is if is possible to change once the property of foo and not change it in the constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I trying to change the properties of an object only one time. And not changing when I create a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is if is possible to change once the property of foo and not change it in the constructor?

The short answer: No.

That's because every time the constructor is called and `this.foo = "foo";` is executed, you are creating a *new* property. The properties you create on `Obj.property` and `Obj` are completely irrelevant actually. They are completely separate properties, defined on different objects, not `this`.

Just look at `Obj` and `obj` more closely:

[image]

You can see three different `foo` properties and I noted which operations create them. Hopefully this makes it clearer why setting the enumerability of `Obj.foo` or `Obj.prototype.foo` has no influence on `obj.foo`.

---

`this.foo = "foo";` creates an enumerable property. If you don't want it to be enumerable then you have to create it with `Object.defineProperty` instead. Again, the properties you create on `Obj` and `Obj.prototype` have nothing to do with the one you create on `this`.

Comment: So, the best case is: change the properties in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, you have to create the property exactly how you want it. As I said, `Obj.foo`, `Obj.prototype.foo` and `this.foo` are three completely separate properties.